# Sell a device containing Google apps without very first boot experience?

Tags: setup-wizard

I bought a Chinese smartphone yesterday in its sealed package, but after powering up the device, It started from Home screen and the SetupWizard was pre-configured by default.

**Is it possible for the end user to buy an Android device coming pre-configured without the very first boot screen AKA SetupWizard?**

**Edit:** Does Google prohibit this habit, any sources please!

Comment: Of course no if its brand new. It could be a refurbished one.

Comment: questions around legal issues are off topic. Please amend the title and question accordingly

Comment: Thing is, manufacturer ROMs could come without any setup wizard entirely. Many custom ROMs do exhibit this behavior.

Comment: I modified the title, the main issue is not about legal/illegal issues but it's about buying an Android device preloaded with with Google apps without Setupwizard.

Comment: Do not confuse Android with Google services, specifically Google Play services. Android is a purely open source OS that anyone can use and implement as they see fit within the terms of the Apache 2.0 Software license. Many implementations of Android use Google services, such as Google Play, but it is not mandatory. Google has guidelines for using their services and part of Google service is a setup wizard but I could find no reference to state that it has to be used or even installed, you could very well have to do it all manually.

Comment: Thanks, so manufacturers are not blamed for this habit of bypassing setupwizard while there is no obligation from Google. And end user should not worry about that point.